# Cannot sava data in database in notification file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel Notification and i want to save data in my database table if i write my insert query then i'm getting following error otherwise Notification are running :

> TypeError: Return value of App\User::getLogNameToUse() must be of the
> type string, null

This is the query

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {   
        $users = User::find($notifiable->id);
        $users->verification_link=$link;  
        $users->save();
        ...
        ...
     }
```

> Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, LogsActivity;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'role_id', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Models\Role::class);
    }
 

}
```

Comment: check if the method `getLogNameToUse` exists in your model, trait or parent class you may be extending

Comment: @MikeRoss: No there is no method `getLogNameToUse`, i'm using spatie package for logs management

Comment: can you add your code of your user model?

Comment: @MikeRoss: Added Model code Please check, link for Spatie package : https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v1/advanced-usage/using-multiple-logs

Comment: Giving you an error for [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/blob/0da6f05060364bb9a15c528d459445d52606d781/src/Traits/LogsActivity.php#L131) part of the package code. have you modified anything from `config/activityLog` file?? specifically `default_log_name` ?

Comment: @MikeRoss: No i have not modified anything in the config, Notification are working if i remove my database insert query

Comment: added an answer, if that does not work, debug what you get in `eventName` of that method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error is with the `logName` and without looking at more code and data it is difficult to pinpoint exactly what is wrong.

Following could work

```
/**
 * Get the log name to use for the model.
 * 
 * @param  string  $eventName
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogNameToUse(string $eventName = ''): string
{
    return Str::kebab(Str::plural(class_basename($this)));
}
```

This is just overriding the piece of code causing issue. Give it a try.